# (<any>window).SomeLibrary.SomeMethod(arg1,arg2)?

Tags: javascript, angular

What is `(<any>window)` when used in Angular2?

I found it while researching the Stripe payment library:

```
(<any>window).Stripe.card.createToken({
  number: this.cardNumber,
  exp_month: this.expiryMonth,
  exp_year: this.expiryYear,
  cvc: this.cvc
}, (status: number, response: any) => {
  if (status === 200) {
    this.message = `Success! Card token ${response.card.id}.`;
  } else {
    this.message = response.error.message;
  }
});
```

http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/07/05/using-stripe-payment-with-angular-2/

Looks like it's something that lets you use global objects inside a controller, but I don't really understand the details. Can't seem to find other answers on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sometimes you’ll end up in a situation where you’ll know more about a
>   value than TypeScript does. Usually this will happen when you know the
>   type of some entity could be more specific than its current type.
>
> **Type assertions** are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m
>   doing.”

It might be in two forms:

```
(<any>window)
```

or

```
(window as any)
```

See also https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

Another way to do the same thing is using `Square bracket syntax`

```
window['Stripe'].card...
```

In this case typescript compiler will work as well

Answer (score 2):

`<any>` indicates a cast in TypeScript, so converting `window` to an `any` indicates that you are no longer bound by the compiler to what it thinks the window object is and what properties it has.

`(<any>window)` is preventing compile time type error checking from flagging the call as invalid.